# When an experiment is performed , one and only one of the events A1,A2,A3,or A4 will occur

Tags: probability, statistics

When an experiment is performed , one and only one of the events $A1,A2,A3$, or $A4$ will occur .

Find the $p(A1),p(A2),p(A3)$ and $P(A4)$ under each of the following assumptions:

a)$P(A1)=P(A2$), $P(A3)=P(A4)$ and $P(A3)=2.P(A1)$

My soluton:
$1=P(A1)+P(A2)+P(A3)+P(A4)$

$1=P(A1)+P(A1)+2P(A1)+2P(A1)$

So,$P(A1)=P(A2)=\frac{1}{6}$

$P(A3)=P(A4)=\frac{2}{6}=\frac{1}{3}$

$b)P(A1)=2P(A2)=3P(A3)=4P(A4)$

My solution:
$1=P(A1)+P(A2)+P(A3)+P(A4)$

$1=P(A1)+\frac{P(A1)}{2}+\frac{P(A1)}{3}+\frac{P(A1)}{4}$

So,$P(A1)=\frac{12}{25}$

$P(A2)=\frac{6}{25}$

$P(A3)=\frac{4}{25}$

$P(A4)=\frac{3}{25}$

Could you please check it for me?

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Also, consider giving respondents a [check mark $\checkmark$](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that is correct.

Next time, you can check easily whether its right by plugging your solutions into your original assumptions and see if they work.